# SELECT Records > 0 and with NO NULL Values

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a query in which I am producing results with rows that contain 0 values. I would like to exclude any rows in which columns B or C = 0. To exclude such rows, I have added the T2.A <> 0 and T2.A != 0. When I do this, the 0 values are replaced with NULLs. Thus I also added T2.A IS NOT NULL.

My results still produce the columns that I do not need which show (null) and would like to exclude these.

```
SELECT
  (SELECT  
      SUM(T2.A) as prem
      FROM Table_2 T2, Table_2 T1
      WHERE T2.ENT_REF = T1.ENT_REF
      AND UPPER(T2.PER) = 'HURR' 
      AND UPPER(T2.ENT_TYPE) = 'POL'
      AND T2.Cov NOT IN ('OUTPROP','COV')
      AND T2.A <> 0
      AND T2.A IS NOT NULL
  ) as B,
  (SELECT  
      SUM(T2.A) as prem
      FROM Table_2 T2, Table_2 T1
      WHERE T2.ENT_REFE = T1.ENT_REF 
      AND UPPER(T2.PER) IN ('I', 'II', 'II') 
      AND UPPER(T2.ENT_TYPE) = 'POL'
      AND T2.Cov NOT IN ('OUTPROP','COV')
      AND T2.A <> 0
      AND T2.A IS NOT NULL
  ) as C
```

Ideally the result will go from:

```
+----+--------+--------+
| ID |  B     |   C    |  
+----+--------+--------+
|  1 |   24   |  123   |  
|  2 |   65   |   78   |  
|  3 |   43   |   89   |  
|  3 |    0   |    0   |  
|  4 |   95   |   86   |  
|  5 |   43   |   65   |  
|  5 | (null) | (null) |  
+----+--------+--------+
```

To something similar to the following:

```
+----+-----+-----+
| ID |  B  |  C  |  
+----+-----+-----+
|  1 |  24 | 123 |  
|  2 |  65 |  78 |  
|  3 |  43 |  89 |   
|  4 |  95 |  86 |  
|  5 |  43 |  65 |  
+----+-----+-----+
```

I have also attempted distinct values, but I have other columns such as dates which are different per row. Although I need to include dates, they are not as important to me as only getting B and C columns with only values > 0. I have also tried using a GROUP BY ID statement, but I get an error that states 'ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have written all the conditions in the `SELECT` clause.

You are facing the issue because the `WHERE` clause decides the number of rows to be fetched and `SELECT` clause decides values to be returned.

In your case, something like the following is happening:

**Simple Example:**

```
-- MANUAL DATA
WITH DATAA AS (
    SELECT
        1 KEY,
        'VALS' VALUE,
        1 SEQNUM
    FROM
        DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        2,
        'IDEAL OPTION',
        2
    FROM
        DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        10,
        'EXCLUDE',
        3
    FROM
        DUAL
)
-- QUERY OF YOUR TYPE
SELECT
    (
        SELECT
            KEY
        FROM
            DATAA I
        WHERE
            I.KEY = 1
            AND O.KEY = I.KEY
    ) AS KEY, -- DECIDE VALUES TO BE SHOWN
    (
        SELECT
            KEY
        FROM
            DATAA I
        WHERE
            I.SEQNUM = 1
            AND O.SEQNUM = I.SEQNUM
    ) AS SEQNUM -- DECIDE VALUES TO BE SHOWN
FROM
    DATAA O
WHERE
    O.KEY <= 2; -- DECIDES THE NUMBER OF RECORDS
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image: output]

If you don't want to change much logic in your query then just use additional `WHERE` clause outside your final query like:

```
SELECT <bla bla bla>
FROM <YOUR FINAL QUERY>
WHERE B IS NOT NULL AND C IS NOT NULL
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thank you! This seemed to get rid of most of them. There are a few in there still so working on rearranging the query to see how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you were on the right track, trying to *group* values.

In order to do that, columns (that are supposed to be distinct) will be left alone (such as `ID` in the following example), while the rest should be aggregated (using `min`, `max` or any other you find appropriate).

For example, as you said that there's some date column you don't care about - I mean, which one of them you'll select - then select the first one (i.e. `min(date_column)`). Similarly, you'd do with the rest. The `group by` clause should contain all non-aggregated columns (`id` in this example).

```
select id, 
       sum(a) a, 
       sum(b) b, 
       min(date_column) date_column
from your_current_query
group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your query right, it would be much easier and more performant, to avoid the lookups in the Select clause. Try to bring it all in one Query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT T2.ENT_REF AS ID,
       SUM(CASE WHEN UPPER(T2.PER) = 'HURR' THEN T2.A END) AS B,
       SUM(CASE WHEN UPPER(T2.PER) IN ('I', 'II', 'II') THEN T2.A END) as C
  FROM Table_2 T2
  WHERE UPPER(T2.ENT_TYPE) = 'POL'
    AND T2.Cov NOT IN ('OUTPROP','COV')
  GROUP BY T2.ENT_REF
)
WHERE B IS NOT NULL
   OR C IS NOT NULL
```